# Routing for react single page application

Tags: reactjs, typescript

**App.tsx**

```
return (
      <div className="App wrapper">
        <SideBar toggle={this.toggle} isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />
        <Content toggle={this.toggle} isOpen={this.state.isOpen} />
      </div>
```

In the App.tsx I am rendering the two components for my single page application. And in Content.tsx i am rendering a Navbar and below that Navbar i am rendering the actual content of the application with the help of route component.

**Content.tsx**

```
class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (

          <Container
            fluid
            className={classNames("content", { "is-open": this.props.isOpen })}
          >
            <NavBar toggle={this.props.toggle} />
            <div>
              <Routes/>
            </div>
          </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

In the Routes component I have defined the routing of the whole page. In a separate component I have created the login form of the application, now I want to integrate the routing for the login page as well i.e. once I clicked on the login button it should redirect to the main page of the application. How can I achieve that? How can i structure the index file of the project?

Comment: Have you implemented any of the login/auth logic at all?  That is a huge task in and of itself.

Comment: In my login function's .then code I have code like this: `if (res.user.type === 'admin' || res.user.type === 'moderator') { history.push('/main',`

Comment: Hi, I haven't implemented the login/auth logic yet. But how my index file structure look like even after implementing the auth logic. Do I need to go with App.tsx or Routes.tsx in the index.tsx file?